# SQL Server on windows container exited

Tags: sql-server, docker

I am following [this article](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/windows/mssql-server-windows/readme.md) to set up SQL Server in a Windows container.

But I am getting this error in the container log:

```
2023-08-08 02:33:22 VERBOSE: Starting SQL Server
2023-08-08 02:33:23 VERBOSE: Changing SA login credentials
2023-08-08 02:33:24 ALTER LOGIN sa with password='Pass@123';ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE;
2023-08-08 02:33:25 []
2023-08-08 02:33:26 VERBOSE: Started SQL Server.
2023-08-08 02:33:27 Get-EventLog : Cannot open log Application on machine .. Windows has not 
2023-08-08 02:33:27 provided an error code.
2023-08-08 02:33:27 At C:\start.ps1:99 char:5
2023-08-08 02:33:27 +     Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "MSSQL*" -After $lastCh ...
2023-08-08 02:33:27 +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2023-08-08 02:33:27     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-EventLog], InvalidOperati 
2023-08-08 02:33:27    onException
2023-08-08 02:33:27     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Power 
2023-08-08 02:33:27    Shell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand
2023-08-08 02:33:27
```

and this in the Event viewer:

```
Error running exec c1666bc33975bb07ae71e25e44fed2a65ca008bebdc26630509dc6b38e8c8ae5 in container: container c91ec8cc69203f8551f53f0126123eced2f67c0e43c8a656f58de4bdb21aee19 encountered an error during hcs::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The user name or password is incorrect. (0x52e)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF7880BA1DB: (caller: 00007FF78806E19A) Exception(4) tid(39c) 8007052E The user name or password is incorrect.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess] 
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
```

I have tried to set a new complex password, `check_policy=off` while creating sa login.

debug start.ps file, but nothing works as off now.

Comment: What does the title and first line of your question have to do with the rest? What do you mean by _"exists"_?

Comment: SQL Server in Windows containers got dumped by Microsoft [a couple of years ago](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/update-beta-program-for-sql-server-on-windows-container-is/ba-p/2516639). The only supported mechanism now is SQL Server Linux containers via [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server).

Comment: What is the RUN cmd you used to launch the container?

Comment: Documentation itself says "Note: These images are provided AS-IS. Microsoft currently does not support running SQL Server on Windows Containers in a production scenario."

Comment: Hey thanks for replies and suggestions..I am trying to learn windows container as using Linux container is pretty much straight Forword and it's not production scenario.                                                                                                                
RUN cmd    docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -v C:/temp/:C:/temp/ -e sa_password=<YOUR SA PASSWORD> -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y --name sqlinstance sqlimage

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
Get-EventLog : Cannot open log Application on machine .. Windows has not 
enter code here`2023-08-08 02:33:27 provided an error code.
```

Seems to come from the entrypoint:

https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/windows/mssql-server-windows/start.ps1

```
while ($true) 
{ 
    Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "MSSQL*" -After $lastCheck | Select-Object TimeGenerated, EntryType, Message   
    $lastCheck = Get-Date 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 
}
```

The errors you are seeing are weird, I have seen errors about not being able to access the event viewer once the container has received termination signals.

In any case, the post you are following is from the official MS repo, but the MSSQL on Windows Containers initiative was abandoned several years ago by MS so you are better off looking for something fresher.

The container ecosystem has made huge progress - specially in regards of windows containers - in this past 3/4 years.

I was able to setup a working image using Windows Containers:

https://github.com/david-garcia-garcia/windowscontainers/blob/master/sqlserver2022k8s/readme.md